# Easiest way to Filter Eclipse Console Output text

Tags: eclipse, console, flexbuilder, filtering

I'm asking this in relation to Flex Builder, but it might apply to Eclipse in general.

Trace statements in Flex Builder get sent to an Eclipse Output Console. What is the easiest way to filter this text on the Eclipse side?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to filter (ignore) lines by patterns.

I came across Logback, but it seems like overkill for this scenario. Is there no way to script something like this Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nothing specific to FlexBuilder. If you need such a functionality, you'd need to write an Eclipse plug-in.

Take a look at [grep-console](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console) one to start off.

Comment: Grep Console worked for me, but the interface was not intuitive. Here is an article by the author how to use Grep Console: http://marian.schedenig.name/wp-content/static/grepconsole_userguide/

Comment: extremely cryptic and non-intuitive.

Comment: I also found this article useful for filtering out everything except for specific lines: https://marian.schedenig.name/2012/08/12/grep-console-how-to-4-filtering-output-with-the-grep-view/. Once you get a few working, you kinda "got it"

Answer (score 5):

Also [GrepClipse](http://grepclipse.sourceforge.net/) may help. Also available on the [Eclipse Martket](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grepclipse).

Answer (score 3):

there is also [Easy Console Grepper](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easy-console-grepper)
which opens up own console, easier at first then grep-console I think. Just define what You searching and it will show **after console execution** lines with searched expression.

Comment: It looks good, but I couldn't find a way how to change the Easy Console Grepper console font size.

Answer (score 2):

Please use [Easy Console Grepper](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easy-console-grepper) Eclipse Plugin as this is much easier and more intuitive than grep-console.